# Looping through values in a matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, variables, double, iteration

I have a Matrix M and I want to run a loop in Matlab whereby the loop variables i,j run through all M(i,j). Can someone provide the syntax please?

Answer (score 2):

First you should first look whether there is a way you could do something using vector operations rather than loops, this is Matlab's strength and usually runs faster. However, if you need to use loops (which sometimes you cannot get around), there are two ways you could do this, the first is to use a single indexing variable (`numel` is the number of elements in the matrix), this goes through the matrix column by column.

```
for i = 1:numel(M)
    M(i) = %your code here
end
```

or through each row and column the way you specified (`size(M, n)` where `n` is an integer is the size of the nth dimension (1st is number of rows, 2nd is number of columns, 3rd is the number of levels, ...))

```
for i = 1:size(M, 1)
    for j = 1:size(M, 2)
        M(i, j) = %your code here
    end
end
```